# Get number of samples in rendered image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes

**For a Cycles render, how can I know the number of samples in the rendered image?**

Normally, I would go to the "Render Properties" tab and look at the number of samples there.

I am now trying out a render farm but they do not tell me how many samples are used. They only give the final rendered image. By comparing the render farm's rendered image and my own rendered image, I know that they do not use the number of samples I have set (it is higher than mine).

One way I can do this is by trial and error (keyframe render samples and set step rate then render animation).

Is there a way I can use the compositor (by setting the first few pixels' value to the sample number or cropping image into [samples]x[samples]), burn into image feature, cycles material node setup or some other way to determine the number of samples used in rendering the image?

Comment: Any serious farm will just render the file you gave to them without changing anything.

Comment: @brockmann It is a free render farm so I'm not complaining about the increased samples

Comment: I'd use the render border feature and render a small portion to compare against. @chhdgxhuc